# fstab is empty. Is it possible to generate it from mtab?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

Normally it should be fine with an empty fstab file (except one data disk). It looks like this:

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
LABEL=DATA   /data   ext4    auto,rw,relatime 0 0
```

But I am on an embedded device which boots from a SD card which could be a problem at boot time. I still have the mtab output which looks like this

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=514140k,nr_inodes=128535,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=102844k,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=205680k 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=205680k 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /data ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
data@rpi1:/mnt/fts300gb/ /mnt/fts300gb fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1003,group_id=1004 0 0
```

Is there a way to generate the fstab from the mtab by a *tool* to be sure it will correctly remount all of the above on the next reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: there is no automagic fstab generation tool outside of an install disk of sorts.

I also don't know of any flavors of linux where this is provided outside the installation medium. It seems you already have most of the information. The one thing I would keep in mind is that your root filesystem needs to be mounted with a 0 1 and all the other filesystems 0 2. Meaning that fsck pass checks happen first on the root filesystem and then any others. The 0 refers to whether the filesystem should be dumped and this has been deprecated for quite a while as there are faster ways to backup data than from a filesystem dump.

You can remove all the lines in there that are tmpfs devpts devtmpfs...those are generated during the boot process. Here's the fstab from my raspberry pi (I presume you are doing this on a second raspberry pi based on your data@rpi1 entry in mtab):

```
# cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
/dev/vglocal00/timemachine  /mnt/TimeMachine hfsplus rw,force,exec,auto,users 0 3
```

As you can see, there's not much in my raspberry pi's fstab, but the mtab shows a bit differently:

```
#cat /etc/mtab
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=219832k,nr_inodes=54958,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=44800k,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=89580k 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/mapper/vglocal00-timemachine /mnt/TimeMachine hfsplus rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8 0 0
```